# How can i scan a number and check if it's already in an array with recursion?

Tags: c, recursion

I need to fill an array with different/distinct numbers,in other words, how can i scan a number and check if it's already in the array with recursion?

```
void getss(int array[], int i,int n)
{   int j;
    int num=array[i];
    if (i > n-1)
        return;
    if(!scanf("%d", &array[i])){
        printf("Illegal input!");
        exit(1);
    }
    /*if(checkdif(array,size+1,n,num)==0)
    {
        printf("Incorrect Input!");
        size++;
    }*/
    j=i+1;
    if(array[i]==array[j]){
            printf("Illegal input!");
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Aside: you have `if(!scanf("%d", &array[i]))`... but you should check for, in this case, a return value of specifically `1`. No other value will be good, such as `EOF` which is also not `0`.

Comment: What is the sense of using scanf() on an `int` array? Also searching a number in an array is typically done iterative.

Answer (score 0):

```
void foo(int n) {
   for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
      ...
   }
}
```

can be written as

```
void foo(unsigned i, int n) {
   if (i >= n)
      return;

   ...
   foo(i+1, n);
}
```

Comment: this how you to move to the next iteration bud do i need another function to check if the number i inserted already exist in the array ?

Comment: By passing `i+1` for the the next call's `i`, as I showed.